# Facing issue with UISwitch on/off

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios6, uiswitch, hiddenfield

There are 6 switch controls in the screen. At one time only one switch should be enable.If 5th switch is on then, one label and one text field should be visible either it should be hidden.

I am facing issue, when 5 switch is changed to on from off and again changed to off. The label and text filed should be hidden but it's not working as per requirement.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.sw_switch1.on = NO;
    self.sw_switch2.on = NO;
    self.sw_switch3.on = NO;
    self.sw_switch4.on = NO;
    self.sw_switch5.on = NO;
    self.sw_switch6.on = NO;

    lbl_desc.hidden = YES;
    txt_desc.hidden = YES;

}


-(IBAction)switchChange:(id)sender
{

        if(sw_switch1.isOn)
        {
            //self.sw_switch1.on = NO;
            self.sw_switch2.on = NO;
            self.sw_switch3.on = NO;
            self.sw_switch4.on = NO;
            self.sw_switch5.on = NO;
            self.sw_switch6.on = NO;

        }


        else if(sw_switch2.isOn)
        {
            self.sw_switch1.on = NO;
            //self.sw_switch2.on = NO;
            self.sw_switch3.on = NO;
            self.sw_switch4.on = NO;
            self.sw_switch5.on = NO;
            self.sw_switch6.on = NO;

        }


        else if(sw_switch3.isOn)
        {
            self.sw_switch1.on = NO;
            self.sw_switch2.on = NO;
            //self.sw_switch3.on = NO;
            self.sw_switch4.on = NO;
            self.sw_switch5.on = NO;
            self.sw_switch6.on = NO;

        }
        else if(sw_switch4.isOn)
        {
            self.sw_switch1.on = NO;
            self.sw_switch2.on = NO;
            self.sw_switch3.on = NO;
            //self.sw_switch4.on = NO;
            self.sw_switch5.on = NO;
            self.sw_switch6.on = NO;

        }

        else if(sw_switch5.isOn)
        {
            self.sw_switch1.on = NO;
            self.sw_switch2.on = NO;
            self.sw_switch3.on = NO;
            self.sw_switch4.on = NO;
            //self.sw_switch5.on = NO;
            self.sw_switch6.on = NO;
            lbl_desc.hidden = YES;
            txt_desc.hidden = YES;

        }

        else if(sw_switch6.isOn)
        {
            lbl_desc.hidden = NO;
            txt_desc.hidden = NO;
            self.sw_switch1.on = NO;
            self.sw_switch2.on = NO;
            self.sw_switch3.on = NO;
            self.sw_switch4.on = NO;
            self.sw_switch5.on = NO;
            //self.sw_switch6.on = NO;
        }


    [self viewWillAppear:NO];

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this

```
if(sw_switch5.isOn)
        {
            self.sw_switch1.on = NO;
            self.sw_switch2.on = NO;
            self.sw_switch3.on = NO;
            self.sw_switch4.on = NO;
            //self.sw_switch5.on = NO;
            self.sw_switch6.on = NO;
            lbl_desc.hidden = NO;
            txt_desc.hidden = NO;
        }
        else 
        {
            lbl_desc.hidden = YES;
            txt_desc.hidden = YES;
        }
```

My suggestion is you should use tag value also for each switch control.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.
    sw_switch1.tag = 101;
    sw_switch2.tag = 102;
    sw_switch3.tag = 103;
    sw_switch4.tag = 104;
    sw_switch5.tag = 105;
    sw_switch6.tag = 106;
    self.sw_switch1.on = NO;
    self.sw_switch2.on = NO;
    self.sw_switch3.on = NO;
    self.sw_switch4.on = NO;
    self.sw_switch5.on = NO;
    self.sw_switch6.on = NO;

    lbl_desc.hidden = YES;
    txt_desc.hidden = YES;

}
```

**Edit:** Use the tag value like this `if((theSwitch.tag == 105) && self.sw_switch5.on)`.
Now you can the try the below optimized code

```
-(IBAction)switchChange:(id)sender
{
    UISwitch *theSwitch = (UISwitch *) sender;
    BOOL switchState = theSwitch.on; //this method is called when changed to on or off.

    self.sw_switch1.on = NO;  // force all switches off
    self.sw_switch2.on = NO;
    self.sw_switch3.on = NO;
    self.sw_switch4.on = NO;
    self.sw_switch5.on = NO;
    self.sw_switch6.on = NO;

    lbl_desc.hidden = YES;// force the label and textfield should be hidden
    txt_desc.hidden = YES;

    theSwitch.on = switchState; // recover the state set by the user, so at a time only one switch should be on

    //now hide or unhide the labels depending on the state of switch 5 only

    if((theSwitch.tag == 105) && self.sw_switch5.on){
    lbl_desc.hidden = NO;
    txt_desc.hidden = NO;
    }
    else{
        lbl_desc.hidden = YES;
        txt_desc.hidden = YES;
    }

    [self.view setNeedsDisplay];

}
```

Comment: By the time when `if(sw_switch5.isOn)` is reached within his code, switch5 is switched off anyway, unless it happened to be switch6 that was on before. While it is good that you suggest the use of tags. You show how to set them but you do not schow how to use them in the action method.

Comment: Thanks tony blue,this is a perfect code,it's working as per my requirement.

Answer (score 2):

You hide the labels (.hidden = YES) when the switched is swithed to on. But you do not unhide (.hidden=NO) when the others are switched off. Your code is a bit unlogical anyway.

I suggest:

```
-(IBAction)switchChange:(id)sender
{

            UISwitch *theSwitch = (UISwitch *) sender; 
            BOOL switchState = theSwitch.on; //this method is called when changed to on or off. 

            self.sw_switch1.on = NO;  // force all switches off
            self.sw_switch2.on = NO;
            self.sw_switch3.on = NO;
            self.sw_switch4.on = NO;
            self.sw_switch5.on = NO;
            self.sw_switch6.on = NO;

            theSwitch.on = switchState; // recover the state set by the user. 

            //now hide or unhide the labels depending on the state of switch 5. 
            lbl_desc.hidden = self.sw_switch5.on;
            txt_desc.hidden = self.sw_switch5.on;

    // [self viewWillAppear:NO];   // What the h.... is this? You are not supposed to call that method. Use self.view.setNeedsDisplay or so instead.

    [self.view setNeedsDisplay];  // This may not be reqired but it forces the view to re-display itself. 

}
```